# How to get data from multiple elements of multiple classes in selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

As written in the question, there are multiple h3 tags and multiple buttons some with same classes while some with different, I want to get the text of h3 tags with class `companyname` and I want to get text of all the buttons with either this class `btn btn-xs btn-success` or this class `btn btn-xs btn-danger`

Here is the html:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
                    <!-- <h3>Did you mean: <a href="/trademarks/search/"></a></h3> -->

                            <div class="searchresult" style="padding-left: 20px;">
                                <!-- <table> -->
                                    <!-- <tr> -->
                                        <!-- <td width="70%"> -->
                                        <div class="row">
                                          <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0; letter-spacing: 0px;" class="companyname">
                                              <a href="/trademarks/953603-susox" style="">
                                                Susox
                                              </a>
                                            </h3> 

                                            <div class="lighter" style="padding-bottom: 5px">ID: 953603</div>

                                            <p>

                                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Registered</button>


                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Class: 5</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Device</button>

                                            </p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>Filed on <strong>05 September 2000</strong></li>
                                                <li>Registered in <strong>GUJARAT</strong></li>
                                                <li>Filed in IPOffice <strong>AHMEDABAD</strong></li>
                                                <li>Published in Journal #9999</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                                              <div style="padding: 0px 0 10px 0; border: solid 0px #CCC;">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" alt="Susox" style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100%" src="https://qcimages.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/store/trademark/7081340/imageshrine/small-1ec5cfa763b881ffa0642b7f6ef802bf.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=GQGLOPQAZ7XLVOTEXYZH%2F20210517%2Fsgp1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20210517T094210Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=900&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=fda1ed68cc66088d64d8cf166341905a61ccc1fac868781b75c8ab78828c587f">
                                              </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="searchresult" style="padding-left: 20px;">
                                <!-- <table> -->
                                    <!-- <tr> -->
                                        <!-- <td width="70%"> -->
                                        <div class="row">
                                          <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0; letter-spacing: 0px;" class="companyname">
                                              <a href="/trademarks/1190452-susox-t2" style="">
                                                Susox T2
                                              </a>
                                            </h3> 

                                            <div class="lighter" style="padding-bottom: 5px">ID: 1190452</div>

                                            <p>

                                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Abandoned</button>


                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Class: 5</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Word</button>

                                            </p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <ul>
                                                
                                                <li>Registered in <strong>HARYANA</strong></li>
                                                <li>Filed in IPOffice <strong>DELHI</strong></li>
                                                
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="searchresult" style="padding-left: 20px;">
                                <!-- <table> -->
                                    <!-- <tr> -->
                                        <!-- <td width="70%"> -->
                                        <div class="row">
                                          <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0; letter-spacing: 0px;" class="companyname">
                                              <a href="/trademarks/1190450-susox-200" style="">
                                                Susox 200
                                              </a>
                                            </h3> 

                                            <div class="lighter" style="padding-bottom: 5px">ID: 1190450</div>

                                            <p>

                                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Abandoned</button>


                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Class: 5</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Word</button>

                                            </p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <ul>
                                                
                                                <li>Registered in <strong>HARYANA</strong></li>
                                                <li>Filed in IPOffice <strong>DELHI</strong></li>
                                                
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                            </div>


                        
                       
 



            </div>
```

> XPATHS:
>
> H3's A tag: `//h3[@class='companyname']`
>
> Button: `//div[@class='col-sm-12']/p/button[@class='btn btn-xs btn-danger']`
> or: `//div[@class='col-sm-12']/p/button[@class='btn btn-xs btn-success']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find elements by tags (if you want the look for all `<h3>` tags or by class name. For the first one, you should use:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')

for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

or find by class name:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('btn btn-xs btn-success')

for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Take account that you also have methods named `find_element_by_<class_name|tag_name>` that only return one element (the first that it found)

Comment: In finding by classname, there are 2 classes, I want to keep the text of boith elements in order in order

Answer (score 2):

You can get this to an elements list by using '[find_elements](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/web_element/)'. Then iterate it using a loop and inside the loop place the code to getText(). Then put it into a list and you can get all the texts from that list when you need to use it.

For example:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'abc')

for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
```

Here it prints the text. Instead of that you can add it to a list and return the list from that.